# How to get the last characters of a string

Tags: c#

I would like to ask question about formatting strings in C#. Basically I only want to view the last n characters in the string.

For example:  string = ("1201  OFFICE PARK RD WDM, APT 708, FLR 2, BLDG 7")
now what i want is just to show:

"APT 708, FLR 2, BLDG 7"

I can actually use a remove method but what if the string.length is not always the same as mentioned in the example? like if I only have "1201  OFFICE PARK" or "FLR 2,BLDG 7"  Appreciate any help on this. Thanks!

Comment: How will you decide on the value of `n`? Is `n` dynamic based on the string value? Or is it a constant value?

Comment: The value of n is dynamic. Thanks for the reply Jaymee

Comment: ok, i will write the line of code here:
 viewService1.Address = customer.ServiceAddress.SingleLine.Replace(Constants.NEW_LINE, Constants.CARRIAGE_RETURN);
for example: viewService1.Address = "1201  OFFICE PARK RD WDM, APT 708, FLR 2, BLDG 7"; 
so the value on n cannot be determined in this point.

Comment: Adrian, you should explain your requirements better. There must be some logic to determine n

Comment: Maybe you want all characters following the first comma?

Comment: @Adrian - in plain English/pseudo code - tell us what `n` should be. Should it be all letters after a certain character in the string? Should it be based on spaces? i.e. last 3 'blocks' characters? You need to explain your requirements.

Comment: yes Jaymee, it shoud be based on spaces. Thanks!

Comment: @Doglas, Tha's correct.

Comment: To get the last characters of a string, use `Substring`. Since your question is really "how to determine n", please rewrite your question to be clear.

Comment: @Adrian What you want is the string after the first non whitespace char after the first comma (I think)

Comment: `string result = str.Substring(str.IndexOf(',') + 2);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following your comments, you can work out n.

```
string s = "1201 OFFICE PARK RD WDM, APT 708, FLR 2, BLDG 7";

string subS = s.SubString(s.IndexOf(",") + 1).TrimStart();
```

or if this string is fixed format:

```
string subS = s.SubString(s.IndexOf(",") + 2);
```

Comment: Thanks afrogonabike! Yes that solution (string subS = s.SubString(s.IndexOf(",") + 2); ) works. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Hi afrogonabike, how can I do that? sorry for silly question. I am just new to this forum.

Comment: At the top left of my answer there should be a greyed out tick - click this to accept the answer - it'll then turn green.  This tells people that your question has been aswered and you dont need any more input.  You can also upvote with up down arrows. Up voting helps people to see which answer people think are good.  You may not be able to do this until you have more reputation though.  Thanks

Comment: Also your question has been downvoted quite a bit.  This is because you haven't been very clear in saying what your requirements are e.g. you didn't really say how you needed to calculate n. To avoid this in future try to be clear what you are trying to achieve. Remember that even though you have the answer you need, other people may view this question and it could be useful to them also, this is why stackoverflow is very particular about how questions are asked :)

Comment: This is noted afrogonabike! Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
public string GetEnd (string input, int n)
{
    return input.SubString (input.Length - n, n);
}
```

this should give you the desired result, as long as you know `n`

Comment: Thanks David but yeah, the challenge here is that n is unknown.

Comment: @Adrian but how is `n` determined then?

Comment: This is how we will know the value of startindex:
SubString(s.IndexOf(","))